# How to tile part of texture in fragment shader

Tags: opengl, glsl, defold

Using Defold game engine and it forces textures in the atlas to be a power of 2 (384x216 -> 512x256).
Defold doesn't have support for parallax background and only options are:

1. Managing multiple sprite positioning with code
2. Manage it with shader on a single sprite.

The first option is not an elegant and optimized way to do, so I go with option Nr.2.

I have a pretty simple shader code that takes the scale and offset of the initial sprite. It works if the sprite is in size of power of 2. But I have practically no knowledge more than this, so I don't know how to tile part of the texture (original not a power of 2). I can calculate and give a uniform that has proportions vec2(384/512, 216/256).

```
varying mediump vec2 var_texcoord0;
uniform lowp sampler2D texture_sampler;
uniform lowp vec4 tint;
uniform lowp vec4 scale;
uniform lowp vec4 offset;
void main()
{
   // Pre-multiply alpha since all runtime textures already are
   lowp vec2 uv = vec2(var_texcoord0.x *scale.x +offset.x, var_texcoord0.y *scale.y +offset.y);
   gl_FragColor = tint * texture2D( texture_sampler, uv);
}
```

I expect to get tiled background but it has empty space because of forced power of 2.

Comment: So what`s your question? Your shader code seems reasonable, just bear in mind that internal GL texture coordinates range from 0.0 to 1.0 in each direction, whereas anything that exceeds that range will be wrapped around according to the texture wrapping mode.

Answer (score 2):

So I got help in Defold community and ended up with fragment shader like this:

```
varying mediump vec2 var_texcoord0;

uniform lowp sampler2D texture_sampler;
uniform lowp vec4 tint;
uniform lowp vec4 size; //actually vec2 of pecentage (x,y)
uniform lowp vec4 scale;
uniform lowp vec4 offset;

void main()
{
    lowp vec2 uv = vec2(var_texcoord0.x *scale.x +offset.x, var_texcoord0.y *scale.y +offset.y);
    uv = vec2(mod(uv.x, size.x), mod(uv.y, size.y));
    gl_FragColor = tint * texture2D( texture_sampler, uv);
}
```